# Coding printf with array of function pointers

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to code the printf function. The problem is that my code is getting very messy and I need some help to try to make it organized and working (hopefully). I have been told that I should use "array of function pointers" so I tried below (ft_print_it) as you can see but I do not know how to how to structure my code so that I can use a big array of function pointer to put every function like int_decimal_octal and friends. Can you help me on that? Where can I call them from?

Also, I realized the little function below (cast_in_short) is giving me the same result as printf if I write the output with my ft_putnbr. My second question is thus: Can I make my printf work with little functions like this? Thank you so much.

```
int cast_in_short(int truc)
{
    truc = (short)truc;
    return (truc);
}    

/*
     here in the main I noticed that I get the same behaviour
     between my putnbr and printf thanks to my little function
     cast_in_short. This is the kind of function I want to use
     and put into an array of pointer of functions in order
     to make my printf work
*/

int main()
{
    int n = 32769;
    n = cast_in_short(n);

    ft_putnbr(n);

    printf("\n");

    return (0);
}

/* function to launch ft_print_it */

int ft_print_str_spec(va_list ap, char *flag)
{
    if (ft_strlen(flag) == 1)
        ft_putstr(va_arg(ap, char *));
    else
    {
        ft_nbzero(ap, flag, 0);
        ft_putstr(va_arg(ap, char *));
    }
    return (1);
}

int ft_print_oct(va_list ap, char *flag)
{
    if (ft_strlen(flag) == 1)
        ft_putnbr(decimal_octal((va_arg(ap, int))));
    else
    {
        ft_nbzero(ap, flag, 1);
        ft_putnbr(decimal_octal((va_arg(ap, int))));
    }
    return (1);
}


#include "libft.h"
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char    *ft_strjoin2(char const *s1, char const c);

#include "libft.h"
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int decimal_octal(int n) /* Function to convert decimal to octal */
{
    int rem;
    int i;
    int octal;

    i = 1;
    octal = 0; 

    while (n != 0)
    {
        rem = n % 8;
        n /= 8;
        octal += rem * i;
        i *= 10;
    }
    return (octal);
}
```

Comment: Did you study the source code of `printf` in some free software C standard library?

Comment: Yes I tried but they do not use array of function pointers ...

Comment: You seem to be fairly new to C, why are you trying to implement a complex function like printf?

Comment: Because I have to ! It is a project in my school...

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Comment: @zakk8889 So you have no clue how to C and one of the first assignments they give you is to reproduce a complex low level library function? What kind of school is that?

Comment: Well I did a library with all the string.h functions, I know chained list, I know how to implement backtracking algorithm but this I don't know, this is why I need your help guys!

Comment: I already malloc in a double dimension array all the flags, isn't it a good start? Furthermore, I only need to handle those flags : sSpdDioOuUxXcC and hh h ll l j z. I don't think this is too bad, no? Anybody can help me? Apparently I could get it done with a structure and inside I put a char and my array of function pointers. But I have no idea how to implement it :(

Comment: A simpler way to estimate the needed buffer space is to use vsnprintf(), and double the buffer size until vsnprintf()  doesn't return failure. (retval <= size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to organize your code to avoid the function like your "flag_code" is to use an array of structure. With structure that contain a char (corresponding to the flag) and a function pointer.

For example :

```
typedef struct fptr
{
   char op;
   int (*ptr)(va_list);
} fptr;
```

And instatiate it like that (with { 'flag', name of the corresponding function} ) :

```
fptr  fptrs[]=
{
   { 's', ft_print_nb_spec },
   { 'S', ft_print_nb_up },
   { 0, NULL }
};
```

Then when you know have char after the % (the flag) you can do something like this :

```
  int i = -1;
  while (fptrs[++i].op != flag && fptrs[i].op != 0);
  if (fptrs[i].op != 0)
  {
     fptrs[i].ptr();
  }
```

For exemple if flag = 'S' the while loop will stop when i = 1 and when you call fptrs[1].ptr() you will call the corresponding function in the structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of making your code messy by using function pointers, because in the end you cannot specialize printf function without providing the format, in C there is no function overloading or template functions. My suggestion is to special printf function by type.

```
// print seperator
void p (int end)
{ printf(end?"\n":" "); }

// print decimal
void pi (long long n)
{ printf("%lld",n); }

// print unsigned
void pu (unsigned long long n)
{ printf("%llu",n); }

// print floating point
void pf (double n)
{ printf("%g",n); }

// print char
void pc (char n)
{ printf("%c",n); }

// print string
void ps (char* n)
{ printf("%s",n); }
```

Test [*try here*](http://ideone.com/ygsxZ6)

```
pi(999),p(0),pf(3.16),p(0),ps("test"),p(1);
```

Output

```
999 3.16 test
```

**Another option**

In theory you can define polymorphic print function in a struct, in case you can do something like this. I haven't tested this yet.

```
struct Node
{
    enum NodeType {Long,Double,Char,String} type;
    union {long l,double d,char c,char* s};
};

void p(Node* n)
{
    switch (n->type)
    {
        case Node::NodeType::Long: printf("%ld", n->l);
        case Node::NodeType::Double: printf("%g",n->d);
        case Node::NodeType::Char: printf("%c",n->c);
        case Node::NodeType::String: printf("%s",n->s);
    }
}
```

Comment: @realUser404 OP is trying to find a way of specialization over printf, it's not easy to see how through how messy his code seems. I'm offering a simple version to how to apply that, where my example shows that it can be on the same line, similar to `std::cout` simplicity in C++.